# Why first image in Array doesn't loop the first time around?

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple animation using javascript.  Of course I could use the CSS keyframes, but that would not work for what I need this for, so no CSS solution please.  I threw in a status div just so you see what I mean without actually having to see the images.  JSfiddle below.

Anyway here is the HTML.

```
    <div id="zero-walking"><img src="#" id="zeroImage"></div>
    <div id="statusDiv"></div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
    var index = 0;
    var zero = document.getElementById("zeroImage");

    var zeroArray = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", "images/4.png", "images/5.png", "images/6.png", "images/7.png", "images/8.png", "images/9.png", "images/10.png", "images/11.png"];

    zeroAnimate();

    function zeroAnimate() {



        zero.setAttribute('src', zeroArray[index]);

        index += 1;

        if (index == zeroArray.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        var statusDiv = document.getElementById('statusDiv');
        statusDiv.innerHTML = zeroArray[index];
    }

    setInterval(zeroAnimate, 700);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9zfg3jp/

Comment: In this `for (var i = 0; i< zeroArray.length; i++) { index[i]; }`, what are you trying to do? `index` is a number, not an array.

Comment: My bad I had the for statement in their when I was testing something out, forget to delete for this post

Comment: You should do `index += 1` **after** setting the `innerHtml` of the `statusDiv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block:

```
 index += 1;

 if (index == zeroArray.length) {
    index = 0;
 }
```

Should be at the very end of the function.

Your problem is `index += 1` is happening before you ever do `statusDiv.innerHTML = zeroArray[index];` so it's 1 (not 0) the first time you get there...

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm,  sorry about that for/loop in there earlier, I was testing something else out and forget to delete when I posted this.

Comment: Use `index++` instead of `+=1`. It's easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the index assignment operator to the end of your method here. As it is, you are FIRST increment the index, then doing work, meaning you are skipping the 0 frame...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I ask myself why I help. If you just want to loop over those images it's like:

```
function loopImages(elem, imgs, interval, loop){
  var i = 0, loopy = setInterval(function(){
    elem.src = imgs[i++];
    if(i === imgs.length){
      loop ? i = 0 : clearInterval(loopy);
    }
  }, interval);
}
loopImages(document.getElementById('zeroImage'), zeroArray, 700, true); // loops forever
```